# ApacheHttpTransport [ClassNotDef Exception] [android project doesn't work but console application does] WHY?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am having some problem. When I run an console application in eclipse (non-android) I imported google-api-client-googleapis-1.4-beta.jar google-http-client-1.8.3-beta.jar

It work!!

but when I import the same thing into my android application, it fail at new com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport(); [ClassNotDef Exception]

Then I follow a lot of the post suggesting a list of library, download all of them, and import all of them.... but it still doesn't should The way I import is right click on the project->config build path -> library -> add external jar file..

So once it switch to android application, it can't find the class. I thought I import the class properly, but since I am having the classNotDef I don't think I am. Anyone knows the reason why????

Any Hints will be good.
Or maybe suggest a list of libraries require for project.

Thanks a ton.

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for does not exist in Android's package structure. There are two solutions to this problem:

1: You can check out the [corresponding package's](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) documentation and use a different class.

2: On the other hand you can take the class you want and package it with your application. Then it is guaranteed that it will be found.